# Javascript variable local and global confusion

Tags: javascript, global-variables, local-variables

Here is code.

```
function x() {
    var a = b = 10;
    console.log("In function a:" + a);
    console.log("In function b:" + b);
}

x();

console.log("Outside function b:" + b);
console.log("Outside function a:" + a);
```

Result I expected was, `b` will be undefined outside the function but this is not the case, its printing `b` value even outside the function though `a` is undefined as expected.

Comment: Yeah other question have answered the same thing, should I delete this question now ? I don't know the procedure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't put var before variable declaration, it gets declared as global.

Since you haven't put var before `b`. It got declared as global hence you can see it's value everywhere.

Where as `a` have var and scoped.

[Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) for the same

> Assigning a value to an undeclared variable implicitly creates it as a global variable (it becomes a property of the global object) when the assignment is executed. The differences between declared and undeclared variables are ........[]

Comment: little tip: if the rest of the code allows you (no other errors), you can switch to `mode strict` to track these variables you forgot to declare

Comment: Thank you, I got it know, was confused with it before

Answer (score 0):

You didn't declare `b` as a local variable. You assigned it as part of the expression used to initialize `a`. Since it wasn't declared local to the function, this created a global variable.

To get two local variables with the same initial value, do this:

```js
function x() {
    var b = 10, a = b;
    console.log("In function a:" + a);
    console.log("In function b:" + b);
}

x();

console.log("Outside function b:" + b);
console.log("Outside function a:" + a);
```

Comment: You should either put `+ a` log before or put a try catch as exception is breaking the code.

Comment: @Rajesh The exception is intended, we want accessing `b` outside the function to report an error.

Comment: Ah! then I guess I misunderstood the question. Cool. Also we can close this question as a dupe

Answer (score 0):

As you have don't mentioned the variable type of

> b

It got global scope :)